# Xpath is invalid in Selenium's automated browser

Tags: selenium, xpath, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate some interactions with a website. I am using Chropath to find the absolute xpath's of various elements, then interacting with them in selenium. However, there is one button that selenium responds to with "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". If I open a new chrome browser and navigate to that button, Chropath shows me a valid xpath. However, if I inspect the same element within the browser that selenium opens, chropath reads "It might be a child of svg/pseudo/comment/iframe from different src. XPath doesn't support for them." for the relative xpath and "It might be a child of iframe from different src & it is not supported currently." In the normal Chrome browser, the absolute xpath is

`/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/span[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/input[1]`

and the relative xpath is

```
//input[@value='View Report']
```

Does anybody know why this difference exists? I've also tried the same process using the CSS selector and it yielded the same results.

Comment: _XPath doesn't support for them_ where is the _XPath_? [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Alright, I added the accessible xpath and deleted the screenshots. I agree that "Xpath doesn't support for them" sounds broken, but it's what it is telling me.

Answer (score 1):

As Stomp, suggested you can try putting some wait time before looking for that element. Please make sure that element is not inside iframe which is from different src. Also the element is loaded and enabled when you are trying to interact with it. As I can see this is the input tag so make sure this is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by waiting a few seconds for everything to finish loading before looking up the element. I did this with a time.sleep() statement, but I think a loop could also work quite well and might be more precise.